# Am I identifying this sentence structure incorrectly - simple vs. compound/compound-complex?

Tags: grammar

I've just got this question wrong while doing some practice and I can't see why.

> *This involves reassessing our relationship with water and learning to use it more sparingly*

My answer was that it was a simple sentence:

> *This involves **reassessing our relationship with water** [noun phrase] and **learning to use it more sparingly**[noun phrase]*

However the answers say "compound or compound-complex".

Could someone confirm whether I am right or wrong?

Comment: It's a compound sentence because you've used a conjunction ('and') to join two separate clauses.

Comment: @Jascol Would you analyse 'This involved wining and dining' differently?

Comment: I would as you're not joining two separate clauses. In example above: "This involves reassessing our relationship with water," and "learning to use it more sparingly," are both complete clauses in their own right.

Comment: @Jascol Why is *wining and dining* not two clauses in its own right?

Comment: I think you're right. It has a co-ordination as an object, but it's not a co-ordination of finite clauses. Neither does it have any finite clauses embedded within it.

Comment: @Jascol But the coordinating conjunction "and" joins two noun phrases, not clauses, right? The parts indicated in the sentence are phrases because they do not have both subject and verb, hence they are phrases, not clauses, and it is still a simple sentence.

Comment: @Araucaria: A clause, at its simplest, must contain at least a subject and a predicate. In the case of Edwina's example: "This," would be the subject while "involved wining and dining," would be the predicate to the subject.

Comment: @Araucaria: In the case of "This involved _wining_ and _dining_", it should still be a simple sentence as it is joining two _nouns_ (gerunds). Thus they should be two phrases.

Comment: @Stephenz Sorry I hadn't picked up on it earlier. Your noun phrases highlihgted above are actually verb phrases. The relevant noun phrases would be: "relationship with water," and "it more sparingly." The addition of the verb makes them verb phrases and as a result separate clauses.

Comment: @Jascol In the Op's example *This* is the subject and *involves reassessing our relationship with water and learning to use it more sparingly* is the predicate. More specifically, *involves* is the verb, or predicator, and *reassessing our relationship with water and learning to use it more sparingly* is a direct object which involves a coordination of two gerund participle whose objects are expressed. Edwin's example has two gerund participles whose objects aren't expressed, but the structure of the two sentences is the same.

Comment: @Jascol So, I don't think the OP's actually is a compound sentence sentence. I don't reckon it's complex either, because, as I understand it, a complex sentence would need a finite clause to be embedded in it, whereas the OP's are gerund-participle clauses, not finite ones. What d'you think? [EDIT: For example, I don't think we'd regard *I like drinking and smoking* as a compound sentence]

Answer (score 1):

I'd say what is complex in this sentence is not the whole unit but just the predicate, as it has two heads.